# Iterate through multiple Images using the Selenium WebDriver (C#, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, list, webdriver

I am trying to loop through a list of Images. I always get only one image in my folder. How do I get simultaneously two images in my directory? Is there a small trick to implement the other XPath into the IList (see below HTML Source)? Thanks for any hint!

[image]

```
IList<IWebElement> Imghref = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[@href='../36691/image.htm']"));

foreach (IWebElement eachLink in Imghref)
{
     eachLink.Click();

     var Images = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

     for (int x = 0; x < Images.Count(); x++)
     {
         var ImageUrl = Images[x].GetAttribute("src");
         WebClient DL = new WebClient();
         DL.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, @"C:\Users\Desktop\GoogleImages\.jpg");
                       

     }
                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just rewrite the previously saved image.
Just update this line

```
DL.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, @"C:\Users\Desktop\GoogleImages\.jpg");
```

like this:

```
DL.DownloadFile(ImageUrl, $@"C:\Users\Desktop\GoogleImages\{x}.jpg");
```

Comment: This does not work. Finally, I have two identical images in the folder. It is necessary to implement somehow the second string from the HTML source code ("//a[@href='../36112/image.htm']") into the XPath. I guess, this is the only way to get two different Images in the folder, but I do not really succeed.

Comment: A similar question has been answered by Stemado ( consider following entry to come the full question/ answer) “ Iterating through Web-Pictures (Selenium, Windows Forms, c#) “